# Why some of user data are not updating using SQL in C# winform?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-update

I have 10 columns but only the last 3 are can be edited/updated.
I'm using C# Winform and SQL Server.

Here goes my code

```
DataRow row = (dataGridSrch.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[products]
                    SET Item = @UItem, Brand =  @UBrand, [Part No.] = @UPart, Description = @UDesc, Manufacturer = @UManu, Car = @UCar, Year = @UYear 
                    WHERE Item = @EItem AND Brand =  @EBrand AND [Part No.] = @EPart AND Description = @EDesc AND Manufacturer = @EManu AND Car = @ECar AND Year = @EYear", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UItem", txtEItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UBrand", txtEBrand.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPart", txtEPart.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UDesc", txtEDesc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UManu", txtEMan.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UCar", txtECar.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UYear", txtEYr.Text);
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Item"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row["Item"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Brand"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EBrand", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EBrand", row["Brand"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Part No."].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPart", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPart", row["Part No."].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Description"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDesc", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDesc", row["Description"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Manufacturer"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EManu", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EManu", row["Manufacturer"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Car"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ECar", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ECar", row["Car"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Year"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EYear", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EYear", row["Year"].ToString()); }
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[products]
                    SET Price = @UPrice , Stock = @UStock , Unit = @UUnit 
                    WHERE Item = @EItem AND Brand =  @EBrand AND [Part No.] = @EPart", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPrice", eprice);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UStock", eqty);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UUnit", eunit);
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Item"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row["Item"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Brand"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EBrand", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EBrand", row["Brand"].ToString()); }
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Part No."].ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPart", DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPart", row["Part No."].ToString()); }
                    int update = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
```

The database accepts null value from columns 1 to 10. So some of the data, not the whole row, have `null` values in the said columns

Columns 1 - 7 and 10, have a `DataType` of `varchar(50)`.

Column 8 is Price, have a `DataType` of `decimal(18,2)`. Which will get the user input using a `NumericUpDown` and then be converted to a `double`.

```
double eprice = Convert.ToDouble(numEPrice.Value);
```

Column 9 is Stock, have a `DataType` of `int`.

The parameters are based on the user selected row from the `DataGridView` that is populated by a `Database`. But when editing/updating the data, only columns 8, 9 and 10 are updated. I have tried changing my SQL command to

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [dbo].[products]
                    SET Item = @UItem, Brand =  @UBrand, [Part No.] = @UPart, Description = @UDesc, Manufacturer = @UManu, Car = @UCar, Year = @UYear 
                    WHERE Item = @EItem AND Brand =  @EBrand AND [Part No.] = @EPart AND Description = @EDesc AND Manufacturer = @EManu AND Car = @ECar AND Year = @EYear;
                    UPDATE [dbo].[products]
                    SET Price = @UPrice, Unit = @UUnit 
                    WHERE Item = @EItem AND Brand =  @EBrand AND [Part No.] = @EPart", conn))
```

I also tried removing the update query for columns 8, 9 and 10, and alternating the `Update` query.

But, I can update using my `SQL Server`.

EDIT:

As for SeM suggestion, I changed my if-else condition to this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row.IsNull("Item") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Item"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EBrand", row.IsNull("Brand") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Brand"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPart", row.IsNull("Part No.") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Part No."));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDesc", row.IsNull("Description") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Description"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EManu", row.IsNull("Manufacturer") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Manufacturer"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ECar", row.IsNull("Car") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Car"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EYear", row.IsNull("Year") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Year"));
```

Comment: Little advice: You can simplify your code by writing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row["Item"].ToString() == string.Empty ? (object)DBNull.Value : row["Item"].ToString());` (well you can add new lines to make it more readable if you want).

Comment: Or if it contains `NULL` (from database), you can write this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row.IsNull("Item") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Item"));`

Comment: @SeM, that will shorten my if-else condition right? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Jepher yeap, you're welcome.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange, still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Didn't say it would fix the issue. But definitely something you should probably change.

Comment: @SeanLange, I thought it was interfering with the `DataType`. But I did change it.

Comment: The root of the issue here is a misunderstanding in how NULL works. Nothings is ever equal to NULL. Even comparing NULL to itself will never pass an equality check. So your where predicates will not update all the rows you expect when ANY of the columns that are part of your where clause contain a NULL. You will need to wrap your columns inside ISNULL.

Comment: @SeanLange I have change my `WHERE` clause to this, `(Item = @EItem OR Item  IS NULL)` and it is working, thanks. So even thou I cast this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EItem", row.IsNull("Item") ? (object)DBNull.Value : row.Field<string>("Item"));` doesn't mean that I'm telling that the cell value is `NULL`, if it is `NULL` in the first place?

Comment: Not exactly. When you send in NULL (which appears to be the correct thing here) you have to check for IS NULL. Because even NULL = NULL will evaluate to false. Does that make sense now?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes. Thank you. I have to remember that.